# Which one is correct: Is it become or became?

Tags: grammar

There was a question i saw here and nobody corrected the poster
https://everyknows.com/category/899/how-did-linda-ikeji-became-a-successful-blogger-

it reads thus: How did linda ike became a successful blogger

which one is grammatically correct, is it to use become or became

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely **become**.

This is because **did** has already been used in the sentence.

**did... became** is a reprinting repetition of the past tense and is not grammatically correct.